# Is Xbox Live needed to save progress in Your Shape Fitness Evolved?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, your-shape-fitness-evolved

I don't have Xbox Live and every time I start the game *Your Shape Fitness Evolved* it says it can't connect to Xbox, so it can't save.

Is there a way to save in *Your Shape Fitness Evolved* without an Xbox Live account, or is it required?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I know you can sign up for a free Xbox Live account. You shouldn't need Xbox Live Gold - which does cost money - to make the game happy. You can sign up for the free version [here](https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Flows/AccountCreation/EmailInformation.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You do need an Xbox LIVE account. From [Ubisoft's FAQ for the game](http://yourshapecenter.us.ubi.com/dashboard/faq):

> #### Does anyone know how to track progress on the Your Shape game on the Kinect?
>
> Each time you launch the game you'll access your online progress in Your Shape Center section.

And:

> #### How do I access Your Shape Center?
>
> With your Xbox LIVE Silver or Gold account:
>
> - Load up Your Shape Fitness Evolved on Xbox 360 and log in to your Xbox LIVE Account.

As [Abby mentioned in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64010/is-xbox-live-needed-to-save-progress-in-your-shape-fitness-evolved/64016#comment90114_64010), you don't need to pay for the full-blown Xbox LIVE Gold account: the free Xbox LIVE Silver account will do. You can register for a new account either directly on the console by pressing the Xbox button in the center of your controller, and selecting "Join Xbox Live" or via [the link Abby mentioned](https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Flows/AccountCreation/EmailInformation.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's a dash bug

See solution below

We have identified the issue that is preventing you from playing your Kinect titles unless you are signed in to Xbox LIVE.  This issue will be fixed in a future update.

In the meantime, you may work around this issue by setting up an offline profile with Kinect ID enabled. Please review the steps below:

1. Restart your console
2. Sign into your profile
3. Go to Settings
4. Select Kinect
5. Select Kinect ID Setup
6. Follow the instructions to setup Kinect ID for your profile
7. Launch the game

After launching the game, use Kinect gestures to start the game and sign in rather than using a controller. If you still use your controller in the game you may still experience the same issue.

If you have any concerns regarding this notice, you may either reply to this message or contact Xbox Customer Support directly using the information available at http://www.xbox.com/support/contact and reference the Service Request number above.

Sincerely,

The Xbox LIVE Escalations Team

Comment: It looks like you just copied and pasted an email from somewhere; if so, could you add in where you got it from, please?

Comment: Hi. It's from the Xbox support page - http://www.xbox.com/support